# Find Missing Cover Art in Python

Tags: python, recursion

So what I'm trying to do is iterate through the directory, and for every folder that contains a flac file, check and see if it also contains a "folder.jpg" file. If it doesn't, print the directory to the terminal. Tell me where I'm going wrong.

```
noart = []
def noart():
#pwd is defined
  for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(pwd):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, "*.flac"):
      if "folder.jpg" not in os.getcwd():
        noart.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Comment: what is the result you're currently getting?

Comment: I'm getting a dump of every FLAC file, regardless of whether "folder.jpg" is in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `os.listdir` on the `os.getcwd()`:

```
noart = []
def noart():
#pwd is defined
  for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(pwd):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, "*.flac"):
      if "folder.jpg" not in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        noart.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

`os.getcwd()` just returns the **path** of the current working directory:

```
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/aj'
>>> os.listdir(os.getcwd())
['Desktop', 'Documents', ...]
```

Comment: Now I'm getting "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'append'"

Comment: give the list and the function different names

Comment: you might also want to `continue` after appending, otherwise you will get many dupes in the collection list

Comment: Okay. I'm still getting a dump of all the FLAC files. It doesn't seem to be effectively searching for "folder.jpg"

Comment: I don't think he is ever changing directories which means `os.getcwd()` remains the same

Answer (score 0):

Besides the point A.J. made about using `os.listdir`, you also check the wrong folder for folder.jpg (`os.getcwd()` doesn't ever change, use the same name for a list and function, and repeat the check for every "*.flac" file.

Instead you should try:

```
def noart():
    result = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(pwd):
        if any(fn.endswith(".flac") for fn in filenames):
            # Check once if any of the files match *.flac
            if "folder.jpg" not in filenames:
                # Check for art
                result.append(root)
    return result
```

Comment: This works. I'll have to familiarize myself with any()

Comment: How would I check for both folder.jpg and Folder.jpg?

Comment: @Ted You could use `if all(art not in filenames for art in ("folder.jpg", "Folder.jpg")):`